# Newton Raphson code for MLE - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, newtons-method, mle

```
newtonraphson <- function(ftn, x0, tol = 1e-9, max.iter = 100) {
 x <- x0
 fx <- ftn(x)     
 iter <- 0
 while ((abs(fx[1]) > tol) & (iter < max.iter)) {
  x <- x - fx[1]/fx[2]
  fx <- ftn(x)
  iter <- iter + 1
  cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x is:", x, "\n")
 }
 if (abs(fx[1]) > tol) {
  cat("Algorithm failed to converge\n")
  return(NULL)}
  else {
  cat("Algorithm converged\n")
  return(x)}
}

X <- c(3,1,2,0,6,8,4,5,7,0)    
n <- 10
lambda <- seq(0,10,0.01)
ftn <- function(p) {
 for (i in 1:10){
 fp <- sum(X[i])*log(lambda) - 10*lambda
 dfp <- (1/lambda)*sum(X[i]) - 10
 }
 return(c(fp,dfp))
}

newtonraphson(ftn, 0.1, 1e-06)
```

This is my code to find the maximum likelihood estimate of lambda.
However, I got this error:

```
Error in while ((abs(fx[1]) >= tol) & (iter <= max.iter)) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I can't seem to resolve the problem. Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Comment: Well don't let `lambda` start at 0. Do something like `lambda <- seq(0.1,10,1e-06)`. What is `X`? Why `sum(X[i])`? `sum(X)` should do it but no data for `X` so one can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for the input. X is `X <- c(3,1,2,0,6,8,4,5,7,0)`. As for `sum([i])`, I was trying to express the log likelihood of poisson: `log(λ) = logλ∑Xi − nλ − ∑LogXi!` Does that seem right to you?

Comment: Not really. Why are you doing `lambda <- seq(...)`? Use parentheses in `ftn` in the first term. Why are you not using  the function argument `p` in `ftn`? This will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the MLE of `lambda` from a Poisson distribution.
However you are solving `ftn(lambda)=0` which does not give the maximum of the likelihood (assuming that the argument p is actually a value for `lambda`).

From [Poisson distribution in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) the MLE of `lambda` is `sum(X)/length(X)`.

You should be setting the derivative of `ftn` to zero and solving for `lambda`. You do not need your `newtonraphson` for that.

Solve `(1/lambda)*sum(X[i]) - 10=0` which will give you the expression from Wikipedia. (10 is `length(X)`).